# How to use compile-run package on heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

i have to use the compile-run to compile (C , C++ , Python , Javascript) codes comming from front end.

locally i used the compile-run and compile correctly.

but i have to use upload the back end on Heroku.

after uploading i tried the same route with the same json data and got error that about no compiler is found.

how to use the compilers after uploading to heroku.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.